# Displaying text and an image in line with each other within a div and then aligning the contents of the div to the center?

Tags: html, css

Basically I have two different headers (different colours) that I have made sit on top of each other how I want but I also have a logo (the smiley face) that is meant to sit next to the headers. And once its in it's place next to (horizontally in line with) the two headers, I want the whole package (the logo and the headers) to be horizontally aligned to the center of their div (.box).

This is a simplified version of my problem and I tried to include all relevant code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
         <h1 class="header1">Hello</h1>
         <h1 class="header2">World</h1>
        <img src="http://i303.photobucket.com/albums/nn157/sal-ad_daze/smiley-face.png"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.container {
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.box {
    width: 50%;
    height:10%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
}
h1 {
    font-family:Arial;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.header1 {
    color: red;
    padding-top:15px;
}
.header2 {
    color: blue;
}
img {
    width: 10%;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9yWFf/

Add or change whatever you want in the Fiddle that will accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for the format edit. Please make sure to check out the fiddle though as you get a visual result. Thanks.

Comment: Did you want like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9yWFf/3/ I have added text-algin: cetner to .box

Comment: unfortunately not Tushar. They have both moved as a unit and are horizontally aligned as a unit (like I want), but the text and the image are on top of one another, I want them to be next to each other horizontally. Thanks.

Comment: @user2756012 : I have posted the answer with the code of yours, If you need the header text one after another remove display property

Comment: @user2756012 : what about my answer. Am I fortunate enough or not :D :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9yWFf/7/)**

Wrap your header1 and header 2 in a div and give `float:left` like this :

```
 <div class="Left">
         <h1 class="header1">Hello</h1>
         <h1 class="header2">World</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: yes this is good thanks. however the header and logo are not horizontally aligned in the box. how would i go about doing this? thanks

Comment: you can do that playing with margin.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are expecting:

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color:#dfdfdf;border: 2px solid;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.box {
    width: 50%;height:10%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {font-family:Arial;line-height:30px;padding:0;margin:0; display:inline-block;}
.header1 {color: red;padding-top:15px;}.header2 {color: blue;display:inline-block;}

img {
    width: 10%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9yWFf/8/)

Comment: unfortunately not, as the two headers are now on the same line. perhaps some changes to paddings or margins can fix this?